# Android JuiceSSH endless prompt to enter Interactive Aunthentication password

Tags: networking, ssh

I am new to network stuff. Normally I connect to the internet provided by the student dormitory using the login client that they provide.

But it is inconvenient as I always have to switch on my laptop to connect it and when my laptop goes to sleep mode, the connection is broken. So, I tried something called SSH (in particular JuiceSSH), and tried to connect using my android smartphone. I followed all the steps written on this [website](https://www.smarthomebeginner.com/connect-via-ssh-from-your-smartphone/) , when I tried to connect, it asked me for the password, after I typed in the password, it still keeps asking me for the password, but not saying that the password is wrong.

Can anyone tells me what's going on and how to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Where do you try to connect? From what network?

Comment: Who provided you login client and what that client is? Are you sure they are providing connectivity through a SSH server?